# angular2-cli ng2 serve problems with typescript exclude property

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

I try to serve a sample application with angular2-cli

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cli

But always encounter with the same error : Error in .src/main.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exclude' of undefined at applyDefaults ...

I found some discussions about the version selection of typescript.
But i see always same error again even though i tried the different versions of typescript.(by package.json)

Is there anyone can accomplish to serve successfully that angular2-cli ?

My system is consisting of :

npm -v : 3.10.10

node -v: 6.9.4

tsc -v: 2.1.5 (But tried different versions from package.json dependency)

Comment: You need to get your information in the ng2 cli from here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli. That link in your question is not a good source.

Comment: i thought that github.com/angular/angular-cli is not related with angular2

Comment: You're mistaken. That is all it is for, ng2, and now ng4. It is the official ng-cli.

Comment: thank you R.Richards; so i understand the https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cli is not the official one and i should use the github link but i would prefer a npm package link. However not problem.

Comment: Right, get all you bits and instructions from the GitHub link put in my comment. That should actually work for you.